# How do i fix the problem with gem command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed ruby (2.7.0) using

```
snap install ruby
```

before this, I removed ruby 2.3.0 by deleting all its files, after

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

but now the `gem` command just doesn't work. I have reinstalled it, but whenever I use `gem`, I get this message,

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/gem: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Ruby is currently installed in

```
/snap/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system `PATH` is determining the wrong direction for `gem`.

> `PATH` is an environment variable on Unix-like operating systems, DOS, OS/2, and Microsoft Windows, specifying a set of directories where executable programs are located. In general, each executing process or user session has its own `PATH` setting. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)))

You can fix the problem by finding out which directory is being prioritized using `which -a gem`, then re-ordering your `PATH`.

I made a script to achieve this, here: [`reorderPathForExe.sh`](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/f4f83b23386111bedd7f8199949601af)

To run this script, just use `git clone` and `chmod +x`, then pass the executable you want fixed as the argument to `reorderPathForExe.sh` (i.e., `./reorderPathForExe.sh gem` for you):

```sh
git clone https://gist.github.com/f4f83b23386111bedd7f8199949601af.git
cd ./f4f83b23386111bedd7f8199949601af
chmod +x ./reorderPathForExe.sh
./reorderPathForExe.sh gem
```

Answer (score -2):

you should probably be installing ruby with [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).